# Entity SaveChanges() for both insert and update?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm having a function that should both update and insert, using the entity framework.

Was wondering if SaveChanges should be used in both cases?

```
if(Something == newThingy)
//do something
myobj.SaveChanges();
```

or is it done differently?
/M

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it should.

Comment: I see I made an error about UpdateObject; I was thinking about ADO.NET Data services. In Entity you don't need to do this. Just calling savechanges will suffice.